# LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: liferay, liferay-aui

this is my view.jsp. when i click hyperlink on view.jsp i want to display jpop.jsp page in popup? can any one tell me is this possible with this? iam new to liferay.    i have error at LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE cannot be resolved to a type

```
<portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:renderURL var="portletSettingsURL" windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString()%>">
      <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/jsppop/jpop.jsp"/>
 </portlet:renderURL>

 <a href="#" onClick="openConfigPopup()">jsp url</a>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function openConfigPopup() 
    {
        AUI().use('aui-dialog', 'aui-io', 'event', 'event-custom', function(A) {
            var dialog = new A.Dialog({
                    title: 'Configuration',
                    centered: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    modal: true,
                    width: 635, 
                   height: 400,
                }).plug(A.Plugin.IO, {uri: '<%=portletSettingsURL%>'}).render();
            dialog.show();
        });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: did you import <%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayWindowState"%>?

Comment: how to get url of the other portlet? for example i have p1 portlet in that i f i click a hyperlink it need to display p2 portlet on popup menu. how to get url of the p2 portlet?

Comment: Make use of `<liferay-portlet:renderURL/>` and provide portletName attribute

Comment: <liferay-portlet:renderURL
    var="testPopupURL"
    portletName="course_WAR_courseportlet"
    windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString() %>">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="jspPage" value="http://localhost:8080/web/guest/create-course?p_p_id=course_WAR_courseportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_course_WAR_courseportlet_jspPage=%2Fhtml%2Fcourse%2Fedit.jsp" />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL> i have added the above but it saying invalid include of jsp page

Comment: @LuckyBoy If possible can you make your comment as an answer so that this question can be resolved.

Comment: @sudheer: It would be helpful if you can ask your question in the comment as a separate question instead of doing that in this post. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to import

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayWindowState"%>
```

HTH